# Audio sometimes "jumps up" after playing sounds for a while

Tags: audio, windows-8.1

strange issue here. (Let me know if you need any more information)

First off my computer is a Lenovo IdeaPad Flex14-59393810-Black+Silver, with the following configuration:
[image: My computer setup]

I'll be doing something that has sound associated with it (playing music, watching a video, playing a video game, etc.) and for a while the sound will remain at a certain level.

However after an indeterminate amount of time, the sound will suddenly shift up several decibels, as though some software caught itself, realized it's playing sound too low and kicks it up a notch.

I've tried changing settings and stuff but haven't seen any correlation with the effects.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not really sure what could be causing this. If you have Dolby Advanced Audio on your system, maybe it's switching on/off accidentally. You might want to install [Equalizer APO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/) on your system and see if that fixes things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

- Right-click the Microsoft speaker icon in the taskbar and select "Audio devices"
- Click on the Default output device (green check-mark) and the Properties button should become active
- Click Properties
- Click the Enhancements tab
- Ensure "Immediate Mode" is selected
- Scroll down to "Loudness Equalization" and toggle it : uncheck if checked, or select if unchecked
- Click OK
- You may have to reboot

If this doesn't help, fully patch your system using Windows Update including optional
updates (excluding bing), to perhaps refresh some drivers.

Comment: Since the problem occurred non-deterministically, I'm not positive that it fixed it but I believe it has.

Answer (score 0):

Thing that comes to mind is windows going crazy with feature that lowers the volume during the skype call or similar. It might wrongly figure that it has been in a call then try to revert the volume to "normal" thus turning it up.

Try going to sound, select playback devices > communications and for option to reduce the volume during conversations choose "do nothing". 
See if it helps, I've read somewhere that there are several bugs, one of them in skype that makes windows act like you are in a call while you actually aren't.

See if this helps. gl.

Comment: Hmm good thinking but I already had it set to "do nothing". Thanks though